# Json web token in Web api not validating the refresh token after its expiry

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, access-token, jwt

I am using JWT authentication for WEB API using OAuth 2. I am using Refresh tokens mechanism. I am able to generate the refresh token and call API service from it before the expiration time. Once the token is expired , i am calling service to issue new token using refresh token id. But its giving error in my CustomJWTFormat class UnProtect method as it not implement any logic. I am not getting what logic to be implemented to reissue JWT refresh token.

Sample codes for configuring serviec to use JSON web token format:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new   OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(<issuer>),
            RefreshTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(<issuer>)
        };
```

Sample code of my CustomJWTFormat class:

```
public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{

    private const string AudiencePropertyKey = "as:client_id";
    private readonly string _issuer = string.Empty;
    private string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = string.Empty;

    public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer)
    {
        _issuer = issuer;
    }

    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }
        string audienceId = data.Properties.Dictionary.ContainsKey(AudiencePropertyKey) ? data.Properties.Dictionary[AudiencePropertyKey] : null;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(audienceId))
        {
            audienceId = <audience>;
            symmetricKeyAsBase64 = <secret key>;
        }
        else
        {
            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                var audience = _repo.FindClient(audienceId);
                symmetricKeyAsBase64 = audience.Secret;
            }
        }
        var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);
        var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);
        var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
        var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);
        return jwt;
    }

    ///Need logic for this method. Its calling when service is called to generated new token for refresh id
    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
    {
        throw NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample to give you an idea of validating a token.

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebAPI-ManuallyValidateJwt-DotNet/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt

In particular, Global.asax.cs.